# VS Code powershell is not running any ionic command

Tags: powershell, ionic-framework, terminal, visual-studio-code

first my commands was working well but when i installed jdk v8 and generated android apk

after this my VS Code terminal powershell is not running any ionic command
this gives me following error

```
PS E:\Ionic\VU_Solutions> ionic s
ionic : The term 'ionic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,      
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ionic s
+ ~~~~~
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

ionic info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI : 5.2.3

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.0
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: Try to uninstall using `npm uninstall ionic` and re run this `npm install -g ionic cordova`

Comment: ionic is installed globaly, sysem is restarted, error is not resolved